# Extract token from a curl request with shell command

Tags: rest, authentication, oauth-2.0

I've started picking up bash scripting and I'm stuck at something I'm trying to wrap my head around.

I have a curl command that outputs a token and I need to use it in the following command:

`curl -k 'https://server:port/session' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"username":"admin","password":"password"}'`

It then outputs a token here:

> {"token":"ac07098ad59ca6f3fccea0e2a2f6cb080df55c9a52fc9d65"}

I then need to use it in the follow up command

`curl https://server:port/ -k -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'X-Cookie:token=token' -d '`

I was thinking I could output the token to a file, then have a sed command write the token to a file, then the new command use a variable where `token=$token`

Answer (score 0):

[`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) is good for extracting your token in the terminal.

Extract token

```
TOKEN=$(curl --silent --location --request POST https://server:port/session \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data-raw '{
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "password"
}' | jq -r '.token')
```

Usage Token

```
curl --silent --location --request POST https://server:port/some \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header 'X-Cookie: token '$TOKEN
```

I made a simulation demo code by flask
It will return a token with a hard code.
And return X-Cookie form header.

```py
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/session", methods=["POST"])
def session():
    content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
    if (content_type == 'application/json'):
        json = {
            "token": "ac07098ad59ca6f3fccea0e2a2f6cb080df55c9a52fc9d65"
        }
        return json, 201
    else:
        return 'Content-Type not supported!'

@app.route("/test", methods=["POST"])
def test():
    content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
    if (content_type == 'application/json'):
        json = {
            "X-Cookie": request.headers.get('X-Cookie')
        }
        return json, 201
    else:
        return 'Content-Type not supported!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Get token

```
TOKEN=$(curl --silent --location --request POST http://localhost:5000/session \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data-raw '{
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "password"
}' | jq -r '.token')
```

Display token

```
echo $TOKEN
```

Use token

```
curl --silent --location --request POST http://localhost:5000/test \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header 'X-Cookie: token '$TOKEN
```

Result

[image]